# Counting the number of times two different words appear in a string - possible with just one regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say we have a string like "catdogbirdbirdcat". What's the best way to determine, say, whether "cat" occurs exactly twice and "dog" occurs exactly once?

```
 (cat|dog)
```

We can match our string against this regex and get an array back and count up matching elements. Or we could do two separate regexes, one for cats and one for birds, and go from there.

Is there a way to do this with one regular expression all in one pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know if it's the best way, and it's pretty ugly. However, here is one method:

```
/
  ^                  #The start of the string.
(?=                  #A non-capturing lookaround.
                     #so that you can check both conditions.
    (?:              #A non-capturing group.
      (?:(?!cat).)*  #Capture text, that doesn't have cat included.
      cat            #Check for the text cat
      (?:(?!cat).)*  #See above.
    ){2}             #Two of these
    $                #The end of the string.
  )
  (?=                #Then do the same for dog
    (?:(?!dog).)*
    dog
    (?:(?!dog).)*
    $
  )                  #Only one dog though.
/x                   #The x flag just means ignore whitespace for readability.
                     #You can also do this though:

/^(?=(?:(?:(?!cat).)*cat(?:(?!cat).)*){2}$)(?=(?:(?!dog).)*dog(?:(?!dog).)*$)/
```

Comment: Whew! When you put it that way, it seems like just counting the matches from (cat|dog) is a lot simpler. Thanks. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Well... someone else can take this up... I've got to get home.  But in any case, this is how I'd do it.

```
var ar = "catdogbirdbirdcat".match(/(cat|dog|bird)/g).sort()
var i = 0;
while(ar[ar.lastIndexOf(ar[i])] != undefined) {
  i = ar.lastIndexOf(ar[i]);
  //somehow get it in an object
  console.log(ar[i] + " " + (i - ar.indexOf(ar[i]) + 1));
  i++;
}
```